# Authentication hangs after Identityserver3 upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, openid, nuget-package, identityserver3

I did an upgrade of IdentityServer3 Nuget package from v2.0.1 to v.2.6.0.
Now, after that the user submits his login and password, the process of user authentication hangs on the "Please wait..." screen. A rollback to v2.0.1 fix the problem. But I cannot keep this version for other reasons.
Any idea about this? or just a way to diagnose?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In FormPostResponse.html there's a call to app.FormPostResponse.js
In the javascript there's a call to submit the form without waiting for the document to load. This cause the post sent before the form is loaded, and thus the process hangs.
To fix this problem. I created a partial template for _authorizeresponse.html to call a javascript file containing that code:

```
$(function () {
 document.forms[0].submit();
})();
```